# Why scroll event fires along with focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I was working with focus event and scroll event I saw when I focus an element by **TAB** key from keyboard at the same time scroll event which I bind with window also gets fired. To accomplish my requirement I have to stop firing scroll event when i focus with **TAB** key. 
Can anyone help me out ?

Thanks in advance for any type of suggestion regarding this issue. 
The code snippet is given below :

```js
function toggleSection() {
 var elm = document.getElementById("support-bar");
 if(elm.style.right === "") {
  elm.style.right = "0";
 } else {
  elm.style.right = "";
 }
}

function expandIfNot() {
 console.log('Focussed');
 var elm = document.getElementById("support-bar");
 if(elm.style.right === "") {
  elm.style.right = "0";
 }
}

document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
 console.log('Scrolled New');
 var elm = document.getElementById("support-bar");
 elm.style.right = "";
});
```

```css
body {
 height: 100vh;
 overflow-y: visible;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}
footer {
 position: absolute;
 bottom : 0;
 width:100%;
}

#support-bar {
 display: table;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 right:-330px;
 transition: margin-left ease 0.2s;
}
#support-bar-toggle {
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: content-box;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 35px;
 line-height: 35px;
 margin-right: -1px;
 padding: 25px 0;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background: #42b4e6;
 border: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 0;
}
#support-bar-toggle > span {
 display: inline-block;
 color: #fff;
 white-space: nowrap;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: normal;
 -webkit-transform: translate(0, 100%) rotate(-90deg);
 -ms-transform: translate(0, 100%) rotate(-90deg);
 transform: translate(0, 100%) rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
 -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
 transform-origin: 0 0;
}
#support-bar-toggle > span:after {
 content: "";
 float: left;
 margin-top: 100%;
}
#support-bar-icons {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
#support-bar-icons ul {
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#support-bar-icons li {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 110px;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #333333;
 line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<header>
   <h1>Test Gallery</h1>
</header>
<br/>
 <label>Test Label</label>
 <input type="text"></input>
 <button name="button">Click Me</button>
 
 <div id="support-bar">
  <div id="support-bar-toggle" onclick="toggleSection()">
   <span>
    <span>Google Apps</span>
   </span>
  </div>
  <div id="support-bar-icons">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="https://mail.google.com/" title=""  onfocus="expandIfNot()">Email</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://drive.google.com" title="" onfocus="expandIfNot()">Drive</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com" title="" onfocus="expandIfNot()">YouTube</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 

<footer>Copyright &copy; </footer>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well there is technically a scroll event that occurs, isn't it? Since the focus event will fire before, you could always set a flag the time of a frame (using e.g `focused=true; requestAnimationFrame(()=>focused=false)`) but that's not clear why **this** event should not be treated as a scroll event.

Comment: @Kaiido It seems that scroll event occurs when I focus event fires, but I don't know why. Anyway I appreciate your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Yes it occurs because your focused element is outside the current viewport, so browsers will put it into view, by scrolling the document to your element's position.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I noticed another problem, after focus scroll event fires twice in FireFox but in chrome it fires once so for chrome the trick of taking a variable "focused" works but not in FF.